# LinkQ Exception

Tags: c#, linq

I write Linq query for keep on fetching data from database. First loop table don't
have record , so throwing exception. After first loop i have record in the database, my
query is working properly. Below i specified my query give some suggestion first 
loop(no records in table) i have to modify query or query have to change.

Ex:

```
 forloop(History history in historyList)
 {
 History history1 = (from p in context.History
                                    where p.TransferCode == history.TransferCode
                                    select p).First<History>()
                                    as History;    
 if(history1 == null)
 {
   SaveToDataBase(history);
 }
 else
 {
   UpdateToDataBase(history1);
 }
 }
```

Thinks

Answer (score 4):

Try using .FirstOrDefault() in your LINQ query.

```
History history1 = (from p in context.History
                                    where p.TransferCode == history.TransferCode
                                    select p).FirstOrDefault<History>()
                                    as History;
```

If no History item is found, then history1 will be null.
EDIT:

This might be cleaner code for you.

```
History history1 = context.History.FirstOrDefault(h => h.TransferCode == history.TransferCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`. And drop the `as History` part. It's unnecessary.

Comment: No, it won't. `null as History` is just `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FirstOrDefault` extension method.
Also LINQ will be able to figure out your result types, so you don't need to do `as History` or `FirstOrDefault<History>`:

```
History history1 = (from h in context.History
                           where h.TransferCode == history.TransferCode
                           select h).FirstOrDefault();
```